# how to setup HttpOnly flag in JSF 2.0 app on Tomcat 6

Tags: jsf-2, tomcat6, httponly

I have found this solution on Sof [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72304/how-do-i-set-the-httponly-flag-on-jsf-richfaces)
but i had to change it from two causes:

1. there is no .getFacesContext()
   function
2. i don't have a specific cookie file
   (see line
   ourcookiename=yourcookievalue)

---

my code looks like this:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
response.addHeader("Set-Cookie", "; HTTPOnly");
```

original code

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getFacesContext();   
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();    
response.addHeader("Set-Cookie", "yourcookiename=yourcookievalue; HTTPOnly");
```

please correct me if I'm wrong. Thank You in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In jsf 2.0 you can do this:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
facesContext.getExternalContext().addResponseHeader("Set-Cookie", "; HTTPOnly");
```

In this way, you don't need to do the cast to HttpServletResponse. For more documentation about JSF, check [MyFaces Documentation Index](http://myfaces.apache.org/docindex.html).

Comment: Thank You. I hope this will help to prevent XSS attacks